# Different sorting types in a bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I’m currently trying to change the type of sorting of my internet bibliography so that it is not sorted alphabetically, but in the citation order. I already tried without luck this 2 options:

```
\printbibliography[sorting=none, env=onlinebib, type=online, heading=bibintoc, title={Internet Sources}, resetnumbers]
```

And

```
\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\printbibliography[env=onlinebib, type=online, heading=bibintoc, title={Internet Sources}, resetnumbers]
```

This is how my code looks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=nyt,style=authoryear, backend=bibtex8, defernumbers]{biblatex} 

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelnumber}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

% bib environment for numeric citations (@online) from numeric.bbx
\defbibenvironment{onlinebib}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

% taken from numeric.cbx
\providebool{bbx:subentry}
\newbibmacro*{cite:num}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}

% switch citation style based on entry type
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}
  {\ifentrytype{online}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibopenparen}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifentrytype{online}{\usebibmacro{cite:num}}{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \ifentrytype{online}{\bibclosebracket}{\bibcloseparen}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{Wikipedia.27.02.2017,
  author  = {Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia},
  year    = {2017},
  title   = {MALDI-TOF},
  url     = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MALDI-TOF},
  urldate = {2017-06-02},
}
@article{Rouhiainen.2004,
  author  = {Rouhiainen, Leo and Vakkilainen, Tanja and Siemer, Berit Lumbye and Buikema, William and Haselkorn, Robert and Sivonen, Kaarina},
  year    = {2004},
  title   = {Genes coding for hepatotoxic heptapeptides (microcystins) in the cyanobacterium Anabaena strain 90},
  pages   = {686--692},
  volume  = {70},
  number  = {2},
  issn    = {0099-2240},
  journal = {Applied and environmental microbiology},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{Rouhiainen.2004} \parencite{Wikipedia.27.02.2017} \parencite{sigfridsson} \parencite{worman} \parencite{ctan} \parencite{baez/online}


\printbibliography[nottype=online, heading=bibintoc, title={Literature}]
\printbibliography[env=onlinebib,  type=online, heading=bibintoc, title={Internet Sources}, resetnumbers]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution requires Biber.

The `sorting` can no longer be passed to `\printbibliography`.
You will need to use `refcontext`s.
Wrap the online bib in `\begin{refcontext}[sorting=none]...\end{refcontext}`.

```
\printbibliography[nottype=online, heading=bibintoc, title={Literature}]
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=none]
\printbibliography[env=onlinebib,  type=online, heading=bibintoc, title={Internet Sources}, resetnumbers]
\end{refcontext}
```

The citations will automatically pick up the correct context.

In general, `biblatex` does not let us sort different entry types with different schemes; but as in your previous question sometimes there is a way around that.

Comment: The problem is that when i change backend=bibtex8 for biber, my bibliography just disappears.

Comment: @matilarab You need to run Biber and not BibTeX8, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). Since we changed the sorting and labelnumber scheme you also need to clean your auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) before you recompile.